# I don't fully understand how the bounties works?

Tags: support, bounties

I started [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103935/how-to-set-nodes-to-be-excluded-from-a-block-view-based-in-the-url-of-current-no) and set a bounty (50) for it. I didn't get the answer to the question I stated:

> Is this a correct approach? If so, what do I have to do in the view?

The bounty has been granted, but I didn't get the answer I asked for. Just that. I think is easy to give a partial answer just to try to get half a bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [How does the bounty system work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) for the full details; there's a lot of info there and probably not much point in reproducing it all over here.

Just to briefly address your question specifically: whenever I see this asked it usually stems from a simple misconception - until they know differently, people assume that they're offering their rep points *for an answer*. That isn't true.

While it's a great (and I'm sure intended) side-effect, the points you offer are for **the extra attention the question will receive by being featured**. Thereby getting more people's eyes on it, and more chance of someone giving a good answer. It doesn't guarantee you an answer, correct or otherwise.

If you feel you're not getting good quality answers you can:

1. Improve your question - I'm not talking about the specific question you mentioned here, just in general. Can your question be fully understood by someone who's not familiar with the bigger picture? Add more details, clear things up, and just generally improve things. Ask a friend/colleague to proof-read it and make suggestions.
2. Downvote answers you feel are incorrect - you have enough rep, and ironically, had you downvoted the answer that was automatically awarded the bounty, it would've received less than 2 votes, and not been automatically awarded any points at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer clive.